# VBA program to run automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with two tabs and wanted to have a VBA to run automatically and pop up a window message saying "NPV negative! Please enter future Savings!" anytime cell J27 (in both tabs) calculates negative value. 
I have the below code in the Module and when I test and click run it does what I wanted to do but in reality when I change information and cell J27 is a negative number nothing happens. I'm very new with VBA so any help is appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
For Each cell In Range("J27")
    If cell.Value < 0 Then MsgBox ("NPV negative! Please enter future Savings!"), , "Invalid Entry"
Next cell
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `Worksheet_Calculate` subroutine is only going to be triggered when the worksheet that you created it in is recalculated. `Range("J27")` is only looking at the cell in that worksheet, so your loop only iterates one time.

To get the value in cell J27 from both worksheets, you need to specify the sheet and the range for each one.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Sheets("This Sheet").Range("J27").Value < 0 And _
       Sheets("That Sheet").Range("J27").Value < 0 Then 
        MsgBox ("NPV negative! Please enter future Savings!"), , "Invalid Entry"
    End If
End Sub
```

Put that in both worksheets to get it to run when either worksheet is recalculated. (Or, better yet, save it in a separate Module and call it from both `Worksheet_Calculate` subroutines.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I pasted the above code in both worksheets and got Run-time error '9' Script out of range. :-(

Comment: @user9969479 Change `Sheets("This Sheet")` and `Sheets("That Sheet")` to the names of the sheets in your workbook.

Comment: Tried that and still the same error. It only works on one sheet and when I remove And _
       Sheets("That Sheet").Range("J27").Value < 0 Then